# Windows 8: How to bring printer to menu?

Tags: windows-8

Is there way to move this printer shortcut to windows 8 menu (that large and take whole screen)? 
If I click right click, there's no item Add (or attach) to menu, that appear for other application links.

Sorry, I cann't provide English version of image.

[image: Right click menu on Printer shortcut]

Comment: maybe this http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.140 or powershell version here - http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-pin-items-to-51be533c